# A method to categorize variations in time series of images

Tags: time-series, python, pca, scikit-learn, image-processing

I am working with a time series of remote sensing images from a particular area.

Temporal standard deviation (SD) of these images showed high fluctuations at some regions with SD of 1.17 while some show SD as low as 0.08.

I am interested in categorizing/classifying these high and low variation regions in an unsupervised manner using the original time series images.
Performing PCA on original time series does not provide conclusive results as PCA also maximizes the smallest variance in time.

I am exploring option of using `IsolationForest` from `Scikit-learn`. Is there any other method which can be used for this purpose?